# set up triggers for items

Tags: commerce

Any way to set up triggers for items in their cart  to remind buyer to check them out after 30 days?

Answer (score 0):

Yep:

[Commerce Abandoned Cart Notification](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_notification)

> This module allows you to notify your customers by email about their abandoned their cart.

It's in dev so be warned; I'm not aware of any other pre-existing solutions, but writing your own module for this would also be a pretty straightforward option if that module doesn't work for your needs.